# Python: parallel matrix multiplication in neural network without np.dot or np.matmul

Tags: python, matrix, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, multiplication

I want to build a code that can calculate matrix multiplication in a neural network without tensorflow or np.dot or np.matmul.

The following is the piece of the code that I interested in:

```
class Affine:
def __init__(self, W, b):
    self.W = W
    self.b = b
    self.x = None
    self.original_x_shape = None
    self.dW = None
    self.db = None

def forward(self, x):
    self.original_x_shape = x.shape
    x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1)
    self.x = x
    out = np.dot(self.x, self.W) + self.b
    return out
```

The code is a part of forward calculation of a neural net (X*W+b). And it works well.

I want to modify the line `out = np.dot(self.x, self.W) + self.b`. It should work in the same way without np.dot or np.matmul.

The following is my code:

```
class Affine2:
def __init__(self, W, b):
    self.W = W
    self.b = b
    self.x = None
    self.original_x_shape = None
    self.dW = None
    self.db = None

def forward(self, x):
    self.original_x_shape = x.shape
    x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1)
    self.x = x

    rows_A = len(self.x)
    cols_A = len(self.x[0])
    rows_B = len(self.W)
    cols_B = len(self.W[0])

    if cols_A != rows_B:
        print("Cannot multiply the two matrices. Incorrect dimensions.")
        return

    # Create the result matrix
    start_time = time.time()
    out = np.zeros((rows_A, cols_B))

    def matmult(i):
        time.sleep(1)
    # for i in range(rows_A):
        for j in range(cols_B):
            for k in range(cols_A):
                out[i][j] += self.x[i][k] * self.W[k][j]

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        pool = Pool(process_num)
        start_time = int(time.time())

        pool.map(matmult, range(0, rows_A))
        print("Seconds: %s" % (time.time()-start_time))

    return out
```

The modified part is just parallel matrix multiplication. However, the following error occured: `AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'Affine2.forward.<locals>.matmult'`

How can I solve the problem?